# How to remove original file after unzipping it in python

Tags: python

I have some python code to unzip a file and then remove it (the original file), but my code catches an exception: it cannot remove the file, because it is in use.

I think the problem is that when the removal code runs, the unzip action has not finished, so the exception is thrown. So, how can I check the run state of the unzip action before removing the file?

```
file = zipfile.ZipFile(lfilename)
for filename in file.namelist():
    file.extract(filename,dir)
remove(lfilename)
```

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for ZipFile says:

> ZipFile is also a context manager and therefore supports the [with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement.

So, I'd recommend doing the following:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(lfilename) as file:
    file.extract(filename, dir)
remove(lfilename)
```

One advantage of using a with statement is that the file is closed automatically.  It is also beautiful (short, concise, effective).

See also [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the file before removing it.

```
file = zipfile.ZipFile(lfilename)
for filename in file.namelist():
    file.extract(filename,dir)

file.close()

remove(lfilename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first close the file.

```
    file.close()
    remove(lfilename)
```

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
with ZipFile('lfilename') as file:
    for filename in file.namelist():
        file.extract(filename,dir)
remove(lfilename)
```